# Testcafe through Docker does not find test files

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I like to run testcafe test through docker but i receive following error:

```
sudo docker run -u root -v ${PWD}:/e2e -it testcafe/testcafe chromium e2e/*.js
```

> ERROR TestCafe could not find the test files that match the following
> patterns: e2e/e2e.docker.js e2e/e2e.js The "/" current working
> directory was used as the base path. Ensure the file patterns are
> correct or change the current working directory.

I tried a lot of different arguments but never was successful with running the basic test.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your directory with tests was specified correctly.

For example:
`sudo docker run -v /home/username/test-project/tests:/e2e -it testcafe/testcafe chromium e2e/*.js`

Comment: I checked it again, it should be right. The strange this is, that testcafe finds the file: ERROR TestCafe could not find the test files that match the following patterns:
e2e/e2e.js <== thats the file matching the pattern: e2e/*.js but just doesn't execute it.

Comment: @meanimal: What happens if you leave out the glob pattern and include the file name instead?

Comment: If you don't specify quotes around a glob, your shell interpreter will expand it. TestCafe doesn't find test files, it receives them as arguments. You can try to check that the `e2e` directory is mounted correctly with the following command:
`sudo docker run -u root -v ${PWD}:/e2e --entrypoint sh -it testcafe/testcafe -c "ls -l /e2e"`

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a similar error while using the testcafe docker image. Turns out, it was a casing issue for me.

For example, my test files were at this location C:/abc/tests/first_test.js and while mounting the folder I was typing "C" drive in caps, which was throwing an error.

So instead of

`docker run -v //C/abc/:/mytests -it testcafe/testcafe firefox /mytests/tests/first_test.js`

I changed the command to the following with lowercase c

docker run -v //**c**/abc/:/mytests -it testcafe/testcafe firefox /mytests/tests/first_test.js

Note: the 'abc' folder has all the node_modules and dependencies. And tests is a folder within the abc folder in my c drive.

May be this provides a little help just in case if you or anyone is facing similar error.

Cheers :)